lua-widow-control and titles
Consider the following MWE
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lua-widow-control}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hola}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[3][1-13]
\end{document}


The use of lua-widow-control makes the chapter label to divide in 2 lines. How can I avoid that?
My real example uses titlesec also, so a patch solution using it is acceptable as an answer.
EDIT
There are the commands \lwcdisable and \lwcenable to turn lua-widow-control feature on and off in the middle of a document. What is the best place to put those directives in the \titleformat construct (given I am using titlesec) or standard LaTeX sectionformat commands?

You can look at the “Automatically Disabling” section of the manual. This should already be automatic for titlesec and the standard classes though, so this appears to be a bug. I'll try and get a fix out shortly.

Well in my original document (a thesis template) it still happens despite I am using titlesec and a standard class, but I tried replicating the bug without titlesec and I manage to do it so I guessed it was not titlesec fault.

You can add additional commands to the disablecmds key, which will automatically disable lua-widow-control for those commands, preventing it from lengthening the chapter headers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lua-widow-control}

\lwcsetup{
    disablecmds={
        % Standard LaTeX sections
        @sect,
        @ssect,
        % You MUST comment out the following line if titlesec is used!
        @makechapterhead,
        % titlesec sections
        ttl@mkchap,
        ttl@straight@ii,
        ttl@top@ii,
        ttl@part@ii,
    },
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hola}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[3][1-13]
\end{document}


I've added this to the package, so it should work automatically in the next update.

For Chapter 1 you could simply box that line as you'll never need a linebreak, but it also affects the main title, where you might need linebreaking on long titles.
This just drops the disable/enable commands into the standard report chapter heading layout.

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lua-widow-control}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries\lwcdisable \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\lwcenable\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hola Hola}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[3][1-13]
\end{document}

